# Injecting DozerBeanMapper with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, dozer

I'm using Dozer in my Spring services. How to inject a `DozerBeanMapper` into a tested service using JUnit and Mockito?

My java class (if simplified) looks like:

```
@Service
public class UnicornService {
    private final DozerBeanMapper dozer;

    @Autowired
    public UnicornService(DozerBeanMapper dozer) {
        this.dozer = dozer;
    }

    public UnicornDto convert(Unicorn unicorn) {
        return dozer.map(unicorn, UnicornDto.class);
    }
}
```

A test class using JUnit 4 + Mockito + Hamcrest looks like:

```
import static com.shazam.shazamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static com.shazam.shazamcrest.matcher.Matchers.sameBeanAs;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnicornServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private DozerBeanMapper dozer;
    @InjectMocks
    private UnicornService unicornService;

    @Test
    public void testConvert() throws Exception {
        final Unicorn original = ...
        final UnicornDto expected = ...

        // Execute the method being tested
        final UnicornDto result = unicornService.convert(original);
        // Validation
        assertThat(result, sameBeanAs(expected));
    }
}
```

The problem is that a mocked Dozer instance is not mapping objects as expected - by default, Mockito stubs return empty or null objects. And if I remove `@Mock` annotation from the test, it throws NPE!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`@Spy`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.0/org/mockito/Spy.html) annotation on `DozerBeanMapper` object. This will allow you to call all the normal methods of the object while still this object is managed by Mockito (as a mock) and injected into a tested service.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnicornServiceTest {
    @Spy
    private DozerBeanMapper dozer;
    @InjectMocks
    private UnicornService unicornService;
    // ...
```

Comment: Do note the comments on https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-: "Real spies should be used carefully and occasionally", " In most cases, this is not the way you want to design your application".

Comment: @daniu I take this into account. And as you can see I came up with two solutions. Do you think that the alternative solution is better?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I've found is to refactor your code. It seems less attractive to me, because it makes more harm then good, just in the sake of writing tests.

Use injection via setter in the service

```
@Service
public class UnicornService {
    private DozerBeanMapper dozer;

    @Autowired
    public setDozer(DozerBeanMapper dozer) {
        this.dozer = dozer;
    }

    public UnicornDto convert(Unicorn unicorn) {
        return dozer.map(unicorn, UnicornDto.class);
    }
}
```

Refactored test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnicornServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private UnicornService unicornService;

    @Before
    public void injectDozer() {
        final DozerBeanMapper dozer = new DozerBeanMapper();
        unicornService.setDozer(dozer);
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be relying on the mapper creating a proper object at all, just that the service calls the mapper and returns its result. The actual mapping should be tested in a unit test for the mapper. Ie

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnicornServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private DozerBeanMapper dozer;
    @InjectMocks
    private UnicornService unicornService;

    @Test
    public void testConvert() throws Exception {
        final Unicorn original = mock(Unicorn.class);
        final UnicornDto expected = mock(UnicornDto.class);
        when(dozer.map(original, UnicornDto.class)).thenReturn(expected);

        // Execute the method being tested
        final UnicornDto result = unicornService.convert(original);
        // Validate that the call was delegated to the mapper
        assertThat(result, is(expected));
    }
}
```